# TypeError: inputList is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to add dynamic input fields in my project and i am getting this error, i am using array in object data structure.

I am quite not sure what to do next as i am running out of options and i am new to react js. would be great if i can get some help on this.

These are my states

```
const [inputList, setInputList] = useState({
product_docket: '',
product_mix: [{ product: '', contains_percentage: '', quantity: '' }],
```

These are the places where i get my error

```
const handleChange = (e, index) => {
const { name, value } = e.target
const list = [...inputList]
list[index][name] = value
setInputList(list)


const handleAddInput = (e) => {
e.preventDefault()
setInputList([
  ...inputList,
  { product_mix: [{ product: '', contains_percentage: '', quantity: '' }] },
])
```

Here the map return

```
 {inputList.product_mix.map((items, i) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <div key={i} className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-4 mb-2">
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label className="pb-2">
                          Products <span className="text-danger">*</span>{' '}
                        </label>
                        <div className="d-flex d-inline">
                          <CFormSelect
                            aria-label="Default select example"
                            name="product"
                            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
                            value={items.product}
                          >
                            <option selected="selected">Customer 1</option>
                            <option>Customer 2</option>
                            <option>Customer 3</option>
                          </CFormSelect>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col-lg-3 mb-2">
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label className="pb-2">
                          % Containing <span className="text-danger">*</span>{' '}
                        </label>
                        <input
                          className="form-control"
                          type="text"
                          name="contains_percentage"
                          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
                          value={items.contains_percentage}
                          placeholder="%"
                        />
                        <span className="text-danger"></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col-lg-3 mb-2">
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label className="pb-2">
                          Quantity Used <span className="text-danger">*</span>{' '}
                        </label>
                        <input
                          className="form-control"
                          type="text"
                          name="quantity"
                          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
                          value={items.quantity}
                          placeholder="Containing %"
                        />
                        <span className="text-danger"></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col-lg-2 mb-2 mt-4 pt-2">
                      {inputList.product_mix.length !== 1 && (
                        <button
                          className="btn btn-danger ms-2"
                          onClick={(e) => handleRemoveInput(e, i)}
                        >
                          Remove
                        </button>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </>
              )
            })}
```

Comment: Initially your inputList is an object, and then you assign it to an array. So when you do `setInputList([ ...inputList`, it says that inputList is not an array.

Comment: Ya i get that, not quite sure what i am suppose to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial state is an object,

in handleChange, you are setting it as a list. It must stay an object {...inputList}

```
const list = [...inputList] //<-- Changing from object to list 
list[index][name] = value
setInputList(list) //<-- Changing state from object to list

//Correct version
const handleChange = (e, index) => {
const { name, value } = e.target
const list = {...inputList} //<-- object, not array
list.product_mix[index][name] = value
setInputList(list)
```

Then your are trying to iterate the product_mix, but since you didn't specify exactly where in array to iterate, it returns an error.

in handleAddInput, you are again using an array instead of an object

```
setInputList([
  ...inputList,
  { product_mix: [{ product: '', contains_percentage: '', quantity: '' }] },
] //<-- Changing state from object to list


//Correct version
setInputList({
  ...inputList,
product_mix: 
   [...inputList.product_mix, { product: '', contains_percentage: '', quantity: '' }],
})
```

The solution is to not change the object to array. I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do with adding products, since your handleChange does not have the same things as your inputList.

Comment: This is not true, he is trying to iterate through the array `product_mix` that is inside the object `inputList`

Comment: That doesn't work @SlothOverload I am trying to achieve this data structure and adding brackets between the intial state creates a different data structure

Comment: Oh, apologies. I'll fix my answer

Comment: @Giacomo is right, this is the structure i need

Comment: {
  "product_docket": "",
  "product_mix": [
    {
      "product": "",
      "contains_percentage": "",
      "quantity": ""
    },
    {
      "product": "",
      "contains_percentage": "",
      "quantity": ""
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @Mizy Edited. What does onCHange do exactly? you are overriding { product: '', contains_percentage: '', quantity: '' } with list[index][name] = value. Is value the same as that object?

Comment: Onchange actually gets the value from the input and adds it to the state.

Comment: Edited onChange method. Does it work now?

Comment: It does work but i have another problem i am unable to get add and get value of the product_docket.

Comment: inside the map, get the product_docket by inputList.product_docket, set it with setInputList({...inputList, product_docket: "blah"})